# Google Search Appliance feed application not found

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I'm trying to access to our appliance machine name using:

`http://<APPLIANCE-HOSTNAME>:19900/xmlfeed` (of course replacing the appliance hostname by the real one).

But I'm getting an error of page not found. I don't have problems when i access to the control panel on port 8000.

Is in the appliance a switch to allow access to the xmlfeed application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn´t.
There´s  just a "List of Trusted IP Addresses"

If you are not on the trusted list, you´ll get an error page:
"Error - Unauthorized Request"

If not, you should see a "Bad Request" message and a HTTP 400 response:

Check you firewall rules or try accessing 
http://:19900/
If it does answer with a 404 error, you should contact support. Maybe the feed service is down.

Hope this helps,

Pablo